# weblogic 12c response.flushBuffer() issue

Tags: ntlm, weblogic12c

I have a  ntlm filter in a web application deployed on weblogic 12c used to retrieve the logged user client name in order to authenticate it automatically.

My filter class is below.

The problem is that in weblogic `response.flushBuffer()` does nothing.
The status page from browser is 401.

This code works well with Jetty Http Server.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

```
package com.asf.ntlm.filter;  


import java.io.IOException;  


import javax.servlet.FilterChain;  
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  


import jcifs.ntlmssp.Type3Message;  


public class AsfNtlmFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {  


  private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;  


  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {  
  this.filterConfig = filterConfig;  
  }  


  @Override  
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {  
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;  
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;  


  System.out.println("Ntlm filter!!!");  


  String username = null;  
  // first, get the user agent  
  String useragent = request.getHeader("user-agent");  
  // if you're using IE, you can continue  
  // Always do the ntlm check (for IE POST back)  
  try {  
  String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");  
  if (auth == null) {  
  response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");  
  response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
  response.setContentLength(0);  
  response.flushBuffer();  
  return;  
  }  
  if (auth.startsWith("NTLM ")) {  


  byte[] msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));  
  int off = 0, length, offset;  
  if (msg[8] == 1) {  
  byte z = 0;  
  byte[] msg1 = { (byte) 'N', (byte) 'T', (byte) 'L', (byte) 'M', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'S', (byte) 'P',  
  z, (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, (byte) 40, z, z, z, (byte) 1, (byte) 130, z, z, z,  
  (byte) 2, (byte) 2, (byte) 2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z };  
  response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1));  
  response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
  response.setContentLength(0);  
  response.flushBuffer();  
  return;  
  } else if (msg[8] == 3) {  
  // Did Authentication Succeed? All this is always  
  // printed.  


  Type3Message type3 = new Type3Message(msg);  


  System.out.println("osUser: " + type3.getUser());  
  System.out.println("osRemoteHost: + " + type3.getWorkstation());  
  System.out.println("osDomain: " + type3.getDomain());  


  }  
  }  
  } catch (Exception e) {  
  System.out.println(e);  
  }  
  // System.out.println("Suc);  


  try {  
  chain.doFilter(req, res);  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
  System.out.println(e);  
  } catch (ServletException e) {  
  System.out.println(e);  
  }  
  }  


  @Override  
  public void destroy() {  
  filterConfig = null;  
  }  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Weblogic.

I reinstall it and now works well.